# Checkboxes inside a Spring Web Flow

Tags: jsp, checkbox, spring-webflow

I am developing a web which uses Spring Web Flow at a given moment. Inside that flow, there is a point (flow2.jsp) where the user is asked to select from some checkboxes. All the examples I have seen (like [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/spring-mvc-form-handling-vol-3-checkboxes-processing.html) and [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-checkbox-and-checkboxes-example/)) gets the items to fulfill the checkboxes from a Controller class...but since I am using Spring Web Flow, I am using the default flowController:

```
<beans:bean id="flowcontroller" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
<beans:property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

How could I feed those items? Must I hardcode them in the JSP?

Thank you.

EDIT

I ended up doing a similar thing, using my model object to initialize the Map:

```
public Map referenceData(RequestContext context){
    System.out.println("Setting up list");
    Map referenceData=new HashMap();
    list=new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("cb1");
    list.add("cb2");
    list.add("cb3");

    referenceData.put("list", list);

    return referenceData;
}
```

This method is called from the flow.xml:

```
<view-state id="flow2" view="flow2" model="proyecto">
    <on-render>
        <evaluate expression="proyecto.referenceData(flowRequestContext)"></evaluate>
    </on-render>

    <transition on="gotoPageThree" to="flow3"></transition>
    <transition on="goBack" to="inicio"></transition>
</view-state>
```

flow2.jsp is the name of the view:

```
<form:checkboxes items="${list}" path="property-in-my-model"/>
```

This way, it throws an Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'items' must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractMultiCheckedElementTag.setItems(AbstractMultiCheckedElementTag.java:83)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.flow2_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fcheckboxes_005f0(flow2_jsp.java:170)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.flow2_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(flow2_jsp.java:135)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.flow2_jsp._jspService(flow2_jsp.java:81)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.ServletMvcView.doRender(ServletMvcView.java:55)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.view.AbstractMvcView.render(AbstractMvcView.java:187)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:296)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:243)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:221)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I can see the sysout comes before in the console than the Exception, so my model object should have a ready to use list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flow controller is an adapter between the Spring MVC Controller layer and the Spring Web Flow engine. It allows Spring Web Flow to run embedded as a Controller within a DispatcherServlet. Flow controller determines what to do when a request arrives like start new flow execution, resume paused flow execution, stop flow execution.
It does not take care of form elements.

You need to create a class(say for login, login service class) that handles the form related stuff before going to next screen in the flow.

For example, create a Class to handle login flow actions:

```
    public class LoginAction implements Seerilaizable{
        ...
        public void performPostLoginProcess(LoginForm loginForm){
            ..
        }
    }
```

Create a form to hold the form fields defined in a view(usually I use only one form for entire flow with multiple views but depending on requirement we can have many forms per flow):

```
    public class LoginForm implements Seerilaizable{
        //Your jsp view has these fields
        private boolean checkBox1;
        private String textField1;
        ...
    }
```

Define this bean in your dispatcher servlet context like:

```
    <bean id="loginAction" class="package.LoginAction">
        <property>...</property>
    <bean>
```

In your flow:

```
    <start-state id="initializeLoginFlow">
    <action-state id="initializeLoginFlow">
        <evaluate expression="LoginAction.initializeFormObject(flowRequestContext)" result="flowScope.loginForm" />
        <transition to="login" />
    </action-state> 
    <view-state id="login" view="login" model="loginForm">
        <transition on="submit" to="section1">
            <evaluate expression="loginAction.performPostLoginProcess(flowScope.loginForm)"></evaluate>
        </transition>
    </view-state>
    <view-state id="section1" view="section1" model="loginForm">
    ...
```

This way you need to have a serving class to hanlde the flow requirements. Hope this helps.

Edit1: In the form proyecto include List webFrameworkList. Change your reference data as

```
public void referenceData(Proyecto proyecto){
        System.out.println("Setting up list");
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("cb1");
        list.add("cb2");
        list.add("cb3");
        proyecto.setWebFrameworkList(list);
    }
```

In jsp:

```
    td>
        <form:checkboxes items="${webFrameworkList}" path="checkBoxPropertyInModel" /> 
    </td>
```

Comment: I have no access now to the computer where I have my project, I will check this tomorrow...but looks good. Thanks Prasad.

Comment: You need to pass form and not flowRequestContext as : <evaluate expression="proyecto.referenceData(flowScope.proyecto)"></evaluate> Also in the form proyecto do you have List<String> webFrameworkList literal defined? Check edit to my answer.

Comment: Proyecto is actually my model class, I fill a Proyecto class with the data of the forms of all the steps on the Web Flow. My method referenceData is in that class, so i think I sholdnt need to pass any argument to that method. 

I pass the RequestContext because without it didn't work, so I was trying, just in case it needs the context to be visible. 

The <form:form> element has id tagsform and name tagsform.

Comment: In that scenario, referenceData should return the list and not a map and change to
<evaluate expression="proyecto.referenceData(flowRequestContext)" result="flowScope.list"/>

Comment: Worked! Thanks Prasad

Comment: Welcome, I would suggest to go with separate service or controller for each flow instead of doing it in the form. As application grows you better have that separation in place. Just a thought :)